# How do you go about finding the normal acceleration of a plane associated with polar co ordinates?

Tags: dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics

**Question**

A plane, having just taken off, has a constant speed of v=94.3m/s.
When $\theta=20^{o}$, the plane is climbing at an ever steepening rate of 0.17 rad/s.

[image]

What is the normal acceleration of the plane $a_n$ this instant?

---

**My Answer**

I have no idea how to do this since this uses polar co ordinates, and I am quite new to polar co ordinates. No clue, would really appreciate if someone provide hints or a walkthrough.

Comment: what do you mean by normal acceleration? in polars, the acceleration components are radial and tangential

Comment: @DavidQuinn I have no idea, this is so confusing....thats what the question says

Comment: how do you know you have to use polar coordinates?

Comment: If you are so confused, your best course of action is to seek your instructor's help. We can't help you if you can't explain to us where your difficulties are, and the problem isn't clear to begin with.

Comment: the mixing of radians and degrees in the question is a bit strange

Answer (score 0):

A simplistic view of this (probably too simplistic) is to say that as the angle is changing constantly, the path of the plane is approximately (?) circular.

Then the acceleration towards the centre of the circle, i.e. normal to the path, is $$r\dot{\theta}^2=r\dot{\theta}\times\dot{\theta}.$$This is the same as linear speed $\times$ rate of increase of angle, which is $94.3\times0.17$ m/$s^2.$

However I realise that the angle $20^o$ must be somehow relevant, so in all likelihood this is wrong.